# Python multiprocessing performance issues

Tags: python, performance, optimization, multiprocessing, back-testing

I have built a backtester in python which does a complete run in 70 ms. On a single thread (using a for loop) I can run this backtester and it shows normal performance (around 70 ms per iteration):

```py
for q in queue:
    print(backtest(alldata1h, alldata, q['strats'], q['filts']))
```

My problem is the following: whenever I try to run this function using multiprocessing, the performance is much worse (~ 800 ms per backtest).

I have tried doing this using an array of `Process` and `Queue` objects:

```py
def do_workload(q, wk, a1h, ad):
    for w in wk:
        c = backtest(a1h, ad, w['strats'], w['filts'])
        q.put({"Strategy": w['sname'], "Filter": w['fname'], "c": c})
    q.put('DONE')

#Please ignore unnecessary indentation

    for i in range(thread_nr):
        thread_pool.append({"Process": "", "Queue": "", "workload": workloads[i], "workindex": 0, "finished": False})
        thread_pool[i]['Queue'] = Queue()
        thread_pool[i]['Process'] = Process(target=do_workload, args=(thread_pool[i]['Queue'], workloads[i], alldata1h, alldata))
        thread_pool[i]['Process'].start()
    print("Total workload: {} backtests".format(len(queue)))

    while queue_index < len(queue):
        for t in range(len(thread_pool)):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if thread_pool[t]['finished'] == False:
                while not thread_pool[t]['Queue'].empty():
                    res = thread_pool[t]['Queue'].get()
                    if res == "DONE":
                        thread_pool[t]['finished'] = True
                    else:
                        final_results = final_results.append(res, ignore_index=True)
                        queue_index += 1
        print("Read from threads: {}/{}".format(queue_index, len(queue)))
        time.sleep(10)
    print("DONE")
```

and I have also tried this using a `Pool` object:

```py
print("Total workload: {} backtests".format(len(queue)))
from functools import partial
target = partial(do_workload, a1h=alldata1h, ad=alldata)
pool = Pool(processes=thread_nr)
print("Starting pool...")
print(len(pool.map(target, workloads, len(workloads[0]))))
```

My processor has 64 cores and 128 threads, so I gave it a high `thread_nr` (around 100-120), but performance is still horrible.

My question would be the following: is there a way to improve python multiprocessing enough in order to achieve 70 ms per backtest (per process)? Or should I rewrite the whole project (backtester and process manager) in C++ in order to achieve the best performance (using all of the possible threads/ the whole CPU).

Comment: How large is the queue and how quickly does it grow? Spinning up 100 Python processes is going to incur quite a performance hit, I would suggest having max 1 process per core

Comment: @IainShelvington The queue is static. I am storing backtests which need to be tested in the queue variable. It can be very small (700) or very large (100000000). Do you think I can get 64x performance with multiprocessing on 64 cores? Because I have tried it, but performance per backtest is still worse than when I only ran that for loop.

Comment: Try using [multiprocessing.Pool.imap](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap), how large is the chunksize you are using (`len(workloads[0])`)?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have also tried using imap, but performance is not improving...